# Weird dplyr+NSE: using NSE in custom function inside mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I stumbled over an issue when using NSE in a custom function inside `dplyr::mutate`. Consider the following code:

```
require(tidyverse)

f <- function(var) {
  varname <- deparse(substitute(var))
  v1      <- as.name(sprintf("%s.Width", varname))
  v2      <- as.name(sprintf("%s.Length", varname))
  return(substitute(v1 + v2))
}

iris %>% 
  mutate(
    test = f(Sepal) %>% eval()
  )

ff <- function(var) {
  varname <- deparse(substitute(var))
  v1      <- as.name(sprintf("%s.Width", varname))
  v2      <- as.name(sprintf("%s.Length", varname))
  substitute(v1 + v2) %>% eval.parent(n = 1)
}

iris %>% 
  mutate(
    test = ff(Sepal)
  )
```

Here `f` works fine but requires an external call to `eval()` to execute the code inside the `mutate()` environment.
This is of course a bit ugly and leads to a lot of boilerplate code. My best guess at making this work was `ff` which tries to evaluate the constructed expression in its calling environment - which I expected to be the `mutate()` environment. However, this throws a variable-not-found error. 
Any thoughts on how to make this work and what the underlying issue is? Essentially I want allow custom 'macros' in dplyr verbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `!!` tidy eval "unquote" operator:

```
ff <- function(var) {
  varname <- deparse(substitute(var))
  v1      <- as.name(sprintf("%s.Width", varname))
  v2      <- as.name(sprintf("%s.Length", varname))
  substitute(v1 + v2)
}

iris %>% 
  head() %>% 
  mutate(
    test = !! ff(Sepal)
  )
```

Comment: thanks, but that's just a nicer variant of eval, right? Why can't I access the correct envronment directly?

Comment: @Jack Not quite. The `!!` operator does "unquoting", not evaluation. I used it because it feels more natural to me in the context of the new tidyeval. But you can achieve what you were trying by just dropping the pipe `%>%` (that was messing up with the hierarchy of calling environments): `eval.parent(substitute(v1 + v2), n = 1)`